# Выровнять колонки по центру не используя offset bootstrap

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Почему не работают последние два свойства стиля outBox? Вчера писал по поводу masonry, решил полностью перелапатить верстку. Вылетела новая проблема. Опять же, почему не работает `.center-block` если я пишу так:

`<div class="center-block col-sm-5"><div class="outBox"></div></div>`?

В чем тонкость?

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .outBox {
                height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: hotpink;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/libs/bootstrap-grid12.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="center-block col-sm-5"><div class="outBox"></div></div>
            <div class="center-block col-sm-5"><div class="outBox"></div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас колонки должны быть в ров обернуты, это стардарт
и какой бутстрап вы используете?

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли добавить `float: none`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```